# Creates belong_to association after sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, confirmation

I'm trying to make my Rails app as easy as possible to sign up for a new account.  I'm using Devise and just requiring the default `email` and `password/confirmation` fields.

My goal is to create a post sign up wizard where the user will fill in the rest of their profile, which would include `Company name, address, and CC# information`.

So, in the end, a user would `belong_to :company` and a Company would `have_many :users`.

If I declare these in my model from the get-go, the user is required to enter company information, which I don't want them to do at this point.

What's the best course of action to create an association AFTER I've collected the user information and they've successfully logged in to my app?  Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Devise will only add certain fields to your user model if they are not already present. So for example, you can have 30 fields in your user model, and Devise may only need two to be set initially (email and password for instance). Then, you can always update the remaining fields later. The user does not have to be required to enter all the fields from the get-go. That wouldn't be very practical.

The only thing you have to be cognizant of when creating associations, is that there is a link between models through foreign_keys. So a user would link to a company through a unique company key thats included in the user model.

If you add some of your code and where you're getting stuck, I can help address any errors.

Comment: At this point I really don't have any custom code from Devise.  I don't even have any code to build a `Company` object yet either... just knowing how associations work I was questioning whether it's even possible.  In the end, I'd like the user (the first one that signs up and creates the Company`) to be the 'account_admin' and they can add other users that would also belong_to that Company.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to create a post sign up wizard where the user will fill in
>   the rest of their profile, which would include Company name, address,
>   and CC# information.

You can override the `Devise::ConfirmationsController` class like

```
class DeviseOverride::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    if resource.has_all_data?
      sign_in resource
      home_page_path(resource)
    elsif resource.has_partial_data?
      sign_in resource
      complete_form_path(resource)
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Invalid request'
      root_path
    end
  end
end
```

In routes

```
devise_for :users, path: '',
  path_names: { sign_up: :signup, sign_in: :login, sign_out: :logout },
                controllers:  {
                   confirmations: 'devise_override/confirmations'
              }
```

> in the end, a user would belong_to :company and a Company would
>   have_many :users

The post-confirmation form is supposed to post data to some controller where you will save data to relevant user and create resources accordingly.

P.S. [May be this doc will help you](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation#1-override-confirmationscontroller)